# How to enable processing of big memory snapshots in VS2015

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2015, out-of-memory, profiling

I am trying to profile my memory-intensive application to find a way to cut down on its memory consumption. Right now it is using up to 2.5GB of memory (32-bit C# application with /largeaddressaware flag). Using VS2015 diagnostic tools I can take a memory snapshot just fine, but when I try to view its details I consistently get the following error:

`An error occurred while processing the snapshot:
Failed to process managed heap`

I've tried to also patch devenv.exe with /largeaddressaware flag, but it does not seem to help. Is there any way to resolve this issue?

Comment: You are not going to get a "push this button" solution to this problem.  You'll have to tackle this the pragmatic way.  If it uses too much memory now then it also uses too much memory when you run the program with a dataset that's half as big.  But now without the tooling keeling over and less of a hassle digging through a 1.25 gigabyte heap to find out what consumes the most memory.

Comment: @HansPassant That's really sad, because my dataset consists of several large lists of different datatypes and I was hoping to examine thier real, unskewed distribution. Besides, it seems to me that this problem should theoretically be solvable, I've solved it in my application just by setting a single flag, after all(

Comment: Have the same issue with 64 bit VisualStudio 2017 (15.7.3). Seems to be a VisualStudio issue.

Comment: To add to @Stefan's comment incase anyone else encounters this, if you build / run and target the x86 CPU (rather than AnyCPU) that worked for me too.